# How to invoke a method with a generic return type using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to invoke a method with reflection that has a generic return type, like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
    public List<T> GetStuff();
}
```

I get an instance of SomeClass with a call to a Repository's `GetClass<T>` generic method.

```
MethodInfo lGetSomeClassMethodInfo = typeof(IRepository)
    .GetMethod("GetClass")
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass<>);
object lSomeClassInstance = lGetSomeClassMethodInfo.Invoke(
    lRepositoryInstance, null);
```

After that, this is where I try to invoke the GetStuff method:

```
typeof(SomeClass<>).GetMethod("GetStuff").Invoke(lSomeClassInstance, null)
```

I get an exception about the fact that the method has generic arguments. However, I can't use MakeGenericMethod to resolve the return type. Also, if instead of `typeof(SomeClass<>)` I use `lSomeClassInstance.GetType()` (which should have resolved types) `GetMethod("GetStuff")` returns null!

**UPDATE**

I have found the solution and will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the instance of SomeClass returned by `GetClass`, even after the types have been resolved, doesn't allow you to call the `GetStuff` method.

The bottom line is that you should simply construct SomeClass first and then invoke the method. Like this:

```
typeof(SomeClass<>)
    .MakeGenericType(StuffType)
    .GetMethod("GetStuff")
    .Invoke(lSomeClassInstance, null);
```